# Failture installing PyGreSQL with pip

Tags: python, six, pygresql

I am currently trying to install PyGreSQL using `pip install PyGreSQL`, however, when I run the command I get the following error:

```
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 375, in setup_py 
       import setuptools  # noqa
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
       from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filterfalse, map
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
       from setuptools.extension import Extension
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>
       from setuptools.extern.six.moves import map
ImportError: No module named extern.six.moves
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong? From what i can tell, something is wrong with `extern.six.moves`, however, I couldn't find anything about this online...

Comment: Why would you think the problem is with extern.six.moves instead of the missing setuptools?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being due to the setuptools not being correctly installed on my machine. Thanks @Famarri for helping me realize that